# What AI do I need for pizza delivery system?

Tags: neural-networks, object-recognition

For example I want to have a chat bot for pizza ordering.

So far I assume that I need (I'm not sure):

- Context Question Answering (questions about menu, pizzas)
- Entity Recognition (ordering some pizza)

Questions:

- What should development process look like for this kind of neural network?
- Should it be custom model from a scratch or existing model?
- What about language translations of existing model - is it possible to translate text model to another language? We are talking about languages with similar grammar, so translation of words should be enough, but how to do it?